# Colorbox module has no effect

Tags: input-formats, javascript, files

I'd like to use the [colorbox module](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) to show the images in my nodes which are comming from flickr.

I'm using the [flickr input filter](http://drupal.org/project/flickr) which works fine. Now I'd like to get a colorbox to show one image after the other when the user clicks on one of the images of a set.

I installed the colorbox module and the jquery plugin. If I look at the HTML source file everything looks ok, but clicking on the images leads to flickr instead of opening a colorbox. According to the docs of the flickr module, colorbox support should be built in.

Any ideas what's missing?

You can see the non working page at [my blog](http://www.pluess.li/node/22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all it turned out that the colorbox integration is available in the dev version only.

For the record: The dev Version gives you the possibility to set the class and rel. Just us the proposed values *colorbox* and *gallery-all* and colorbox gives you a nice view of all your flickr images on the node.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the flickr integration, but in the included colorbox.js file, it appears that colorbox is looking for images with the `.colorbox` class.

Have you tried adding the `.colorbox` class to the `img` elements in that view? It's possible that the class may have beren [removed by a drupal filter](http://drupal.org/node/1937734).

The relevant Javascript:

```
 $('a, area, input', context)
      .filter('.colorbox') // target class
      .once('init-colorbox')
      .colorbox(settings.colorbox);
  }
```